# Discord.js how to use the event handler?

Tags: event-handling, discord, discord.js

Alright. So I've made an event handler.

```js
const fs = require('fs');
fs.readdir('./events/', (err, files) => {
    if (err) return console.error(err);
    files.forEach(file => {
        const eventFunction = require(`./events/${file}`);
        if (eventFunction.disabled) return;

        const event = eventFunction.event || file.split('.')[0];
        const emitter = (typeof eventFunction.emitter === 'string' ? client[eventFunction.emitter] : eventFunction.emitter) || client;
        const once = eventFunction.once;

        try {
            emitter[once ? 'once' : 'on'](event, (...args) => eventFunction.run(...args));
        }
        catch (error) {
            console.error(error.stack);
        }
    });
});
```

But I'm not sure what I am supposed to put in a file of the folder. I basically wanna do an auto reply file. I added that, but it's not showing any reaction.

```js
client.on('message', message => {

if ((message.content === `<@${client.user.id}> <3` || message.content === `<@!${client.user.id}> <3`)) {
    message.channel.send('<3');
}
});
```

**So, what should I put into the file, to make the bot working?**
Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

When you copy code, [you should always try to understand it](https://medium.com/discordbot/this-is-a-good-event-handler-for-your-first-discord-js-bot-1e338e670697). Here's the original code from the tutorial with comments:

```js
const fs = require('fs'); // fs is the package we need to read all files which are in folders

fs.readdir('./events/', (err, files) => { // We use the method readdir to read what is in the events folder
    if (err) return console.error(err); // If there is an error during the process to read all contents of the ./events folder, throw an error in the console
    files.forEach(file => {
        const eventFunction = require(`./events/${file}`); // Here we require the event file of the events folder
        if (eventFunction.disabled) return; // Check if the eventFunction is disabled. If yes return without any error

        const event = eventFunction.event || file.split('.')[0]; // Get the exact name of the event from the eventFunction variable. If it's not given, the code just uses the name of the file as name of the event
        const emitter = (typeof eventFunction.emitter === 'string' ? client[eventFunction.emitter] : eventFunction.emitter) || client; // Here we define our emitter. This is in our case the client (the bot)
        const once = eventFunction.once; // A simple variable which returns if the event should run once

        // Try catch block to throw an error if the code in try{} doesn't work
        try {
            emitter[once ? 'once' : 'on'](event, (...args) => eventFunction.run(...args)); // Run the event using the above defined emitter (client)
        } catch (error) {
            console.error(error.stack); // If there is an error, console log the error stack message
        }
    });
});
```

Every file in the `events` folder is being required as a javascript file, so we know that it should export an object. The object is stored into the `eventFunction` variable, and a couple of properties are looked at:

- The `event` property is the event that it's listening for, and if not specified it'll default to the filename.
- The `emitter` property is the property that emits the event, which defaults to the bot, which is what we want.
- The `once` property denotes if the event should only trigger once, which is not what we want.
- The `run` property contains the function that will actually be triggered on the event.

Now that we know what properties we need/don't need, we can construct a file to put in the `events` folder:

```js
// export the object so it can be required
module.exports = {
    // we want a message event
    event: "message",
    // we want it to trigger multiple times
    once: false,
    // the actual function
    run(message) {
        if (message.content === "foo") {
            message.channel.send("you said foo");
        }
    }
};
```

Alternatively, if you name the file `message.js`, you can also get rid of the `event: "message"` line as it'll default to that.